# Converting simple IIS 7 ReWrite Rule to Helicon Ape

Tags: url-rewrite-module, helicontech

I need to convert the syntax below (which is for IIS7 URL Rewrite) to Helicon Ape. Can someone shed some light?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule>
                <match url="^api/([.*])$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/(.+)$ /api/index.cfm?$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when using the above code. Just to clarify, I need to be able to process www.acme.com/API/index.cfm/CreateTemplate as www.acme.com/API/CreateTemplate